# Plotting lines behind ROC curves

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc

I am trying to plot ROC curves with ggroc and the 45 degree line as well as a box around the curves:

```
ggroc(list(roc1, roc2, roc3)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("red", "blue", "yellow"),
    legacy.axes = T) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1),
    linetype = "dashed",
    color = "grey") +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1),
    color = "grey", fill = NA)
```

Basically my data shows that the test I´m plotting the curves for doesn´t work so the ROC lines are partially crossing the 45 degree line and are obscured at the beginning and the end by the geom_rect.

I tried `annotate`, `custom_annotation` and `after_stat = FALSE` with the geom objects and couldn´t find any other promising solutions. Is there a way to get the line and the box behind the ROC lines that keeps ggroc? It would probably be possible to rebuild the plot with ggplot and change the order of the layers but I would be happier with a ggroc solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this works for `ggroc`. But in general you can change the order of the geom layers by manipulating the `ggplot` object.

Here is a fake example where I add a `geom_segment` and `geom_rect` on top of a `geom_point` and save the `ggplot` as a variable `p`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data.frame(
  x = seq(0, 1, length.out = 3),
  y = seq(0, 1, length.out = 3)
), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1),
    linetype = "dashed",
    color = "grey"
  ) +
    geom_rect(
      aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1),
      color = "grey", fill = "white"
    )

p
```

[image]

Now we can change the order of the geom layers by rearranging the list of `layers` like so, e.g. putting the `geom_segment` and the `geom_point` on top of the `geom_rect`:

```
p$layers <- p$layers[c(3, 2, 1)]

p
```

[image]

To figure out the order of the layers you can simply print `p$layers`:

```r
p$layers
#> [[1]]
#> geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> mapping: x = 0, y = 0, xend = 1, yend = 1 
#> geom_segment: arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, lineend = butt, linejoin = round, na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> mapping: xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1 
#> geom_rect: linejoin = mitre, na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)

data(aSAH)
roc.list <- roc(outcome ~ s100b + ndka + wfns, data = aSAH)

p <- ggroc(roc.list, legacy.axes = T)  +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1),
    linetype = "dashed",
    color = "grey") +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1),
    color = "grey", fill = "dark blue")

#change order of layers
p$layers <- p$layers[c(3, 2, 1)]

print(p)
```